# sidebar in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display different dynamic sidebar on different pages, how do I access multiple sidebar on my pages.

Answer (score 0):

Place some form of hook on different pages.

Open `sidebar.php` in your themes and check for presence of hook.

Answer (score 0):

You should create files like `sidebar-xxxx.php` and include it, using `get_sidebar(xxxx)` in the different templates and souhld register them on `the functions.php`. If you do not wanna create these files you can register the sidebars on `functions.php` and in the sidebar.php use:

```
global $wp_query;
$page_name = $wp_query->post->post_name;
<ul>
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-'.$page_name) ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new sidebar

and you can link them inc with is page

```
if(is_page(5)) {
 include('new-sidebar.php')
}
```

is page id is 5 lets say thats the id for your home page

just check the ids of your pages and seperate them

if you want them tho show in the page childs to

just write

```
 if(is_page(5) || $post->post_parent) {
     include('new-sidebar.php')
    }
```

zou can even write a function either

Answer (score 0):

For different sidebars, i thing you have to do is to create the sidebar which you want as many as you want and save those sidebars as sidebar1.php, sidebar2.php and so on.

And,just include it in the different pages where you want it to display like this:

```
<?php include('sidebar1.php'); ?>
```

And, like wise for other sidebars of other pages.